# Batch file for loop /D flag not appearing in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've got a small batch file that I want to use to copy a file from one location to many locations that may have different name.

```
for /D %%f in ("%%localappdata%%\Microsoft\Opc*") do (
    for /D %%x in ("%%f\*") do (copy /y user.config %%x\)
 )
```

I'm able to get this to run fine in the command line, but if I try and run my batch script instead, this is all that's shown on the command line:

```
for / %f in ("%localappdata%\Microsoft\Opc*") do (
   for / %x in ("%f\*") do (copy /y user.config %x\ ) 
)
```

It looks like, for whatever reason, the /D flag is getting changed into just /

I'm rather new to batch scripting, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In a batch: `for /D %%f in ("%localappdata%\Microsoft\Opc*") do (` _do not double_ `%` percent sign in `%localappdata%` etc... Unlike `%%f` and `%%x` is right. And astonishing `/` echoed instead of `/D` should not affect `for /D` functionality (hopefully, **haha!**). +1 for your question...

Comment: @JosefZ it looks like you were right, the only problem was the double % around localappdata. Still no idea why /D wasn't echoed correctly, but thanks for the help! If you want to make this an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: In my instance, it was the case that I was mistakenly looping through `%f` instead of `%f\*`. Different problem, same weird error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a batch script: contrary to (correct) doubling the `%` percent sign in `%%f` and `%%x` parameters, do not double `%` in environment variable names like `%localappdata%` etc...

```
for /D %%f in ("%localappdata%\Microsoft\Opc*") do (
    for /D %%x in ("%%f\*") do (copy /y user.config %%x\)
 )
```

However, that *stunning* `/` echoed instead of `/D` should not affect the `for /D` command  functionality (still searching for an explanation).