# Why is the letter D from /D option of command FOR missing in the output?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch file to delete all files and folders except for `TEMP` folder. I noticed the letter **D** of the option `/D` is missing in the output. The script seems to work fine, but I wonder why it's missing.

```
@echo on
@Y:
REM Following dangerous command commented out for safety - magoo
REM for %%f in (*) do del "%%f"
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    if /I not "%%d" == "TEMP" echo "%%d"
)
pause
```

Output:

```
Y:\>for %f in (*) do del "%f"

Y:\>for / %d in (*) do (if /I not "%d" == "TEMP" echo "%d" )

Y:\>(if /I not "TEMP" == "TEMP" echo "TEMP" )

Y:\>(if /I not "test" == "TEMP" echo "test" )
"test"

Y:\>(if /I not "test 2" == "TEMP" echo "test 2" )
"test 2"

Y:\>pause
```

I'm echoing just for test purpose. I will replace it finally with `rd /S /Q`.

Comment: Beats me - but my system does the same thing.

Comment: Is it dangerous because it could delete a whole Y drive? How should I modify it?

Comment: Absolutely! Suppose you don't have a Y: drive - the drive letter will remain unchanged so you'll run that command from your current directory on your current drive. How to disarm? many ways. Removing the command completely. Change 'del' to `echo`, Check that the current drive is indeed Y:

Comment: Changing to drive `Y:` does not mean to change to its root directory, there is actually a current directory for every drive; you could do [`cd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)`/D "Y:\" || exit /B 1` to surely change to the root of `Y:` and also to quit in case of an error (e. g., when `Y:` does not even exist); alternatively use [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)/[`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)...

Comment: Thanks. Replaced ```Y:``` with ```cd/D "Y:\" || exit /B``` and added checking if "TEMP" folder exist.

Comment: As long as it's working should I ignore the fact that the letter D doesn't appear?

Comment: The fact that the letter D doesn't show  seems to be a known bug in Windows batch interpreter (however I'm not ready to google for qualified resource). Just ignore it and run your scripts using `@echo OFF`…

Comment: Interesting (but harmless?) bug. If you combine `/D` with `/R` then only one slash without letter is shown. All forms without `/D` echo properly. @JosefZ - "known bug"? - Do you have any reference(s)? I'd be curious to see what was said.

Comment: @dbenham I met this behaviour _at the least_ >4 years ago at [Batch file for loop /D flag not appearing in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30130576/3439404) … Please note my _still searching for an explanation_ gloss there (still valid:). My OS was _Windows XP_ in those days and I didn't observe any complaint against `FOR /D` functionality in a `.bat`/`.cmd` since…